# Automatically update all row's status column when time has exceeded from stored time Laravel (Task Scheduling)

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I want to check my stored data at database for every minute if `now` time has exceeded `'close_at'` time. So then I can change the `'status'` column to be `closed`.

I've been thinking that I can `->get()` all data from to the table and use looping to check every data's `'close_at'` then change the `status` but that's not effective nor efficient is it?

Got any idea?

Comment: Get all data `where('close_at', '<', now())`

Comment: Do you have a CRON job running to check every minute? Also, don't think there's any other way to check each row but to use `foreach`.

Comment: ah yess right @apokryfos , just get the data needed which is `close_at < now`. Thanks bro

Comment: @fufubrocat yeah... All I can think is using `foreach` hahaha... thanks for the reply!

Comment: @fufubrocat well I can do it each hour, but I need something accurate. Cuz that 'close_at' is the limit time for the job applicants to apply the job. When the status is `closed` they can't apply it anymore

Comment: Just an additional tip: When you use `foreach` to check each job/row, make sure you include `where('status', '=', 'open')` so it'll only check open jobs and omit closed ones. Good luck!

Comment: Okay :D Thanks @fufubrocat !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the above answers into something more comprehensive :

1. Make sure cron is executing Laravel's scheduler every minute :

   ```
   php8.0 /home/yourdomain.com/artisan schedule:run
   ```
2. Make a new Laravel command to execute the relevant logic :

   ```
   php artisan create:command CloseJobs
   ```
3. Write the necessary code in that class - in this case, retrieve all the relevant open jobs which need to be closed and close them, which we can do through mass assignment in one easy line (make sure your 'status' is added to the $fillable array on your model) :

   ```
   protected $signature = 'close:jobs';

   ....

   $jobs = Job::where('status', 'open')->where('close_at', '<', now())->update(['status' => 'closed']);
   ```
4. Tell Laravel to execute that task every minute, in App\Console\Kernel.php :

   ```
   $schedule->command('close:jobs')->everyMinute();
   ```